# Any advice on customising this twitter feed?

Tags: widgets, twitter

I'm really having trouble locating the documentation for the Recent Tweets widget anywhere. It's not a plugin and appears to be native. All I want to do is to be able to move the `tweet_time` underneath the `tweet_text`.

If you take a look at the [website](http://test1.epictraveller.net), you'll be able to see the time of the tweet is on top of the actual tweet text, and I want to reverse the order.

Comment: The "Recent Tweets" widget isn't delivered with WordPress. Do you have a link, where you downloaded it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the [Webzine theme](http://www.uiueux.com/wp/webzine/) - if you take a look at the source, near the bottom, there's a rather hefty chunk of JS that queries Twitter & renders the tweets.

Now whether that code is sat there waiting for you in `footer.php`, or called in from somewhere else, I don't know - if the latter, you'll have to root around the theme folder to find it!

It's worth mentioning that the Twitter user status API is loaded *again* (along with Twitter's own `blogger.js` for the callback) at the very bottom of your site, but it's not actually utilised - you could save yourself some processing (& headaches for that matter) by removing it.